# How do I change the layering of different marks in Swift Charts

Tags: swift, charts

I have a Swift Chart. It has two sets of data plotted. A `BarMark` using `yStart` and `yEnd` to specify minimum/maximum values and a `LineMark` to specify a related value.

I want the `LineMark` plot to be "on top" of the `BarMark` plot, but it always plots the other way around, with the result that the bars obscure part of the line.

How can I change this?

Here is a simple reproduction of my problem

```
struct DataItem: Identifiable {
    var id: Int {
        return month
    }
    let month: Int
    let min: Int
    let max: Int
    let mid: Int
    
    static var data:[DataItem] = {
        
        var items = [DataItem]()
        
        for i in 1...12 {
            let min = Int.random(in: 1...50)
            let max = Int.random(in: 51...100)
            let mid = (max-min)/2+min
            items.append(DataItem(month: i, min: min, max: max, mid:mid))
            print(max,min,mid)
        }
        
        return items
        
    }()
}


import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ChartView: View {
    var data: [DataItem]
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data) { dataItem in
            BarMark(x: .value("Month",  dataItem.month), yStart: .value("Min", dataItem.min), yEnd: .value("Max", dataItem.max))
            LineMark(x: .value("Month",dataItem.month), y:.value("mid", dataItem.mid))
                .symbol(.circle)
                .foregroundStyle(.green)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ChartView(data: DataItem.data)
}
```

In the image, you can see that the first `LineMark` appears on top of the first `BarMark` but the rest are behind.  Why is this and how can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer is a subtle but significant change to the way that the marks are added to the `Chart`.

Using the form in my question

```
Chart(data) {
    BarMark() 
    LineMark()
}
```

results in a chart with effectively a single plot with data represented in two different ways.

If I change it to

```
Chart { 
    ForEach(data) { 
        BarMark() 
    } 
    ForEach(data) {
        LineMark()
    }
}
```

Then I have one chart with two separate plots of two separate data series and the layer order follows the order in which those plots are specified.

Here is the working code:

```
struct ChartView: View {
    var data: [DataItem]
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(data) { dataItem in
                BarMark(x: .value("Month",  dataItem.month), yStart: .value("Min", dataItem.min), yEnd: .value("Max", dataItem.max))
            }
            ForEach(data) { dataItem in
                LineMark(x: .value("Month",dataItem.month), y:.value("mid", dataItem.mid))
                    .symbol(.circle)
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]